# cakePHP 2.0 find('threaded') Issue

Tags: php, cakephp

I am running the following in my Jobs controller.

```
$this->set('jobs', $this->Job->find('threaded', array('conditions' => array('Job.id' => 20))));
```

Now in my view I am displaying `$jobs` in my `foreach` loop fine, but my issue is I have children linked to Job.id using the field parent_id. I know the link works fine because I can see the children in the array.

```
    Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Job] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [parent_id] => 0
                [rght] => 2
                [lft] => 1
                [client_id] => tasd
                [contact] => asdf
                [email] => sdf
                [address] => 
                [lat] => 
                [long] => 
                [user_id] => 1
                [request_type_id] => Electrical
                [date_start] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [date_end] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [date_complete] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [date_closed] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [status] => completed
                [brief_desc] => aasdf
                [desc] => asdfasdf
                [cost_est] => 3434.00
                [cost_actual] => 
                [created] => 2011-12-18 20:39:24
                    [modified] => 2011-12-18 20:39:24
            )


        [Children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 21
                        [parent_id] => 20
```

I would like to display the child jobs under the parent jobs. Exactly how nested comments should work. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the SQL that `find('threaded')` is generating. You are asking for all Jobs with an id of 20 (Rather than all Jobs that are children of Job 20)

Since you have a lft and rght field, I assume you have the Tree behaviour attached. This means you can use `children()`.

```
$this->Job->id = 20;
$this->Job->children();
```

However, this will give you a flat array, rather than a nested array. If you need a nested array then use the lft and rght columns in the `find('threaded')` call.

```
$parentJob = $this->Job->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Job.id' => 20
    )
);

$children = $this->Job->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Job.lft BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($parentJob['Job']['lft'], $parentJob['Job'])['rght']
    )
);
```

Of course you could get that down to a single query, but I'll leave that 'as an exercise for the reader' (I should have been a Textbook writer)

Comment: Thanks Dakota, It seems the array I am getting back now looks more like the array I need to use. What is the best PHP code to use to read this array. The normal foreach statement I am using isn't working at all.

Comment: You'd need to use a recursive function (ideally). Have a look at the link that chetan patel posted. It may be very outdated, but the helper class should give you a good idea what to do (Search the page for **app/views/helpers/tree.php**)

Comment: This answer is good and I know this is old, but the parenthesis are insufficient to close the statement and I believe that the second find should be  'threaded' instead of a 'first'

Answer (score 1):

If anyone want to display the find('threaded') result in view of cakephp, they can use this:

Controller code:

`$params = array('recursive' => -1,'fields' => 'Category.id, Category.name, Category.parent_id');
$categories = $this->Category->find('threaded',$params);`

And show your threaded result in view like this:

```
foreach($categories as $category):
        $category_name = $category['Category']['name'];
        foreach($category['children'] as $children):
              $sub_category = $children['Category']['name'];
        endforeach;
endforeach;
```

I don't know its the proper way to display the result or not, but it's working fine.
Hope its help for someone :)
I'm new to cakephp and learning basics. If found any mistake, please forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

Please Read below link

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/MrRio/2006/09/24/threaded-lists

Comment: I did read that. Its a very old article and I don't believe its using find('threaded')

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I was trying to figure this out today and was able to make it work (somewhat oddly) with the following:

```
$this->set('jobs', 
    $this->Job->find('threaded', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                Job.id' => 20,
                Job.parent_id => 20
            )
         )
    )
);
```

Hope this saves someone some time...